# How to pass a query string to render views context in a template?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to get my template shows a by enter query string like /q?DictionaryItem where the dictionary is in views.

view.py

```
def render_test(request):
context = {'foo': 'bar', 'foz': 'baz'}
return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
...

path('render_test/', views.render_test, name="render_test")

...
```

test.html

```
{{ foo }}

{{ foz }}

{{ request.GET.q }}
```

the url `render_test/?q=foo` shows

```
bar

baz

foo
```

what I want is

```
bar

baz

bar
```

also for the url `render_test/?q=foz` it should show

```
bar

baz

baz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, just add another context variable to your dictionary:

```
def render_test(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar', 'foz': 'baz'}
    context['result'] = context.get(request.GET.get('q', ''), None)
    return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

and render in template

```
{{ foo }}

{{ foz }}

{{ result }}
```

Comment: Hi. This works! But is there another if I don't want to edit`views.py`. Just changing something in template can't do this right?

Comment: Just editing in template is not enough. If you do not want to update the view, then you have to write a custom template tag for this simple task(which is an overkill).